# Reverse relation (one-to-one) lookup not working in Django view (django-plans)

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

I've just installed `django-plans`. They link a `UserPlan` object to the used settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL through a one-to-one relation. As I understand it, this relation does not require a related_name for reverse lookups. Therefore, it should be callable using the Class name in without Caps, e.g. `userplan`.

My problem is that the reverse lookup works in the python shell:

```
>>> from profiles.models import CustomUser
>>> s=CustomUser.objects.get(email="test@test.com")
>>> s <CustomUser: test@test.com>
>>> s.userplan <UserPlan: test@test.com [Starter]>
```

But when I use the code in a view, it returns an **Attribute Error**:

```
'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'userplan'
```

This is the code I'm using in the view:

```
u = CustomUser.objects.get(email="test@test.com")
up = u.userplan
```

First I thought it had to do with `request.user` being a SimpleLazyObject, but even when fetching a "real" user it didn't seem to work in the view.

Any suggestions?

P.S. As you might have noticed, we're using a custom user model.

Comment: Are the apps containing both CustomUser and UserPlan contained in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, they both are part of the INSTALLED_APPS list. I also read that this is required to create the automatic reverse for 1-to-1.

Comment: does it work in the shell if you open a new clean shell and type only the lines you pasted above?

Comment: Clear your pyc files and try again. Also, please copy-paste your exact code.

Comment: @karthikr I removed all the pyc files, no luck. What more code would you like to see?

Comment: I meant to say the exact lines of code which emulate the fetching of the user object and accessing the foreignkey field

Comment: It's right there. That's all I'm doing. Fetching an object and referencing the foreign key through **userplan**. I now even created a dummy table with another one to one field, which works perfectly. Just not with the model from django-plans.

Comment: I also deleted the tables, and migrated again to create the tables again. No luck.

Comment: I also explicitly added a related_name to the UserPlan model, with the samen name as the class. Which shouldn't be necessary, but still doesn't work...